# Bootstrap/AngularJS tooltip position

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I saw that the tooltip isn't right positioned on hover when I scroll down the page..
[image: that's ok]

[image: issue]

```
<div ng-if="item.status == 2" class="icn special" tooltip-placement="top" 
     uib-tooltip="Special">
  <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: try adding `tooltip-append-to-body="true"`

Answer (score 2):

Add `tooltip-append-to-body="true"` - example code:

```
<div ng-if="item.status == 2" 
    class="icn special" 
    tooltip-placement="top" 
    uib-tooltip="Special"
    tooltip-append-to-body="true">
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and wasted hours trying to find a solution. While it is a known problem, the solution is not exactly unique.

Fortunately, I found the answer to my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916732/ui-bootstrap-tooltip-in-a-table-moves-everything-on-the-right)

In my case, I had the uib-tooltip inside a `td`tag which according to [Sanket Achari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4233150/sanket-achari), you have to use `div` after `td`.

In addition to that solution, I had to set `tooltip-append-to-body="false"` for it to work. Previously, I had set this to true. If not set, the default value is `false`.

I am putting this here because the answer provided above [Kimchi Man](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3780749/kimchi-man) does not exactly address my issue and it didn't work for me.